# Matching square brackets in vim

Tags: vim

I am aware of the shortcut for flower braces i.e. Having cursor over `{` and pressing `]}` gets me to the corresponding `}`. How to do the same for matching square brackets? `[]`

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%

Comment: `%` is much simpler than `]}`, and works for both cases.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Something new and useful thing to learn! Thanks :)

Comment: If you are in the middle of one function, not over any curly braces you need to press ]] or ]}, in the case of curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode, try

```
vi[oh
```

`vi[` should visually select the entire block between `[]`, and `o` switch cursor to the front of visual selection, then `h` moves cursor onto `[`.

At the expense of more keystrokes, this works in more cases than `%` where you must hover over the bracket.